# One to many rel in GAE using G data Store Entity

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I want to create one to many relation using Google DataStore entities Something like:

Entity proj=new Entity("Project");
proj.setProperty("name","Project 1");

Now I want to associated multiple user entities with this project

Entity user1= new Entity("User");
user1.setProperty("name", "User1");

Entity user2= new Entity("User");
user2.setProperty("name","user2");

How do I associate multiple users 1&2 to same Project proj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the project reference on the user entity

Comment: I could add "Project name" as an reference on User entity, but that way I will have to keep my project names unique in system. If I search for users of a project, I should get only a project's user.

Comment: Use a reference property or the Project entity id.